# the easiest way to serialize the object with properties

Tags: c#, wpf, image, serialization

I have an `ObservableCollection` that I want to save to a binary file. An item in that collection contains a field of a type `System.Windows.Controls.Image` so while saving I'm getting an error:

```
Type 'System.Windows.Controls.Image' in Assembly 'PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' is not marked as serializable.
```

I think I could try to convert an `Image source` to a `byte[]` variable and save it but I'd like to also save some Image properties like event handlers that I added or Effects.

It there any easy way to do it? or is it even possible?

Comment: You want to serialise an event handler? Huh?

Comment: @krajol As said before, your data item should not contain Image controls. You should declare the image property as either `ImageSource` (and search SO for a solution how to serialize that), or `Uri` or `string` if the images are available via an URL. Also, for the other image features (effects etc.) you would have to find a representation that is easily serializable. You may define an effect by a descriptive string, and define a set of flags that controls which event handlers are attached, and so on. This way you would define something called a view model.

Comment: @Clemens Thank you, I think this is what I expected as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

convert that image to memory stream go through these links

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/dee0e287-b345-4e01-888a-ecfb9c3f40b0/

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/Vsexpressvcs/thread/011c2c24-ffc5-4be5-883b-2430267b33c8

Answer (score 0):

You would need to provide your own serialization surrogate via the [SurrogateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.surrogateselector.aspx). What that serialization surrogate does is entirely up to you.